# Nutcracker problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque

I'd need help with this problem:

> In a nutcracker a walnut is placed 5,0 cm from the fulcrum. To crack the nut in that position you must apply a 120 N force.
>
> What is the force you must apply if the nut is placed 15 cm from the fulcrum?

I would have said 360 N but the book gives 40 N as the answer.

Could you help me understand why 40 N is the answer?

Just to clarify:
this is not homework, I'm asking this on behalf of a fellow teacher whose English is a bit tentative and the book he works with is a translation of Physics by Walker.
The translation of this problem is not very clear at best.

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Can you explain (i.e., edit your post) why you would have thought $360 \textrm{N}$ to be the answer?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I think you must have this the wrong way round, or there's a misprint in the question. If the force required when the nut is at 15cm is 120N then the force required when nut is at 5cm is 40N.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a little guidance rather than a full answer; but what you're looking for is called the "moment":

I think the best way to think about this is a seesaw;  If someone heavy sits closer to the middle of the seesaw, they can balance with a person who's lighter and further away.

This means that as they move closer to the fulcrum, they actually exert less force (or rather, torque) to the other side.

Your question is a variation of "if Dave is 45kg, sitting 1m away from the middle, how far should Sharron sit to keep it level, if she's 135kg".  Thinking it about it this way should explain why the factor of 3 went the wrong direction.

Comment: Isn't the seesaw a first-class lever whereas the nutcracker is a second-class one? Does your reasoning work the same with the nutcracker?

Comment: The concept of moment is (perpendicular) force x distance (from pivot).  It doesn't matter how that force is applied or which direction, or which side.  The classes of lever are just different ways of applying the same physics.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea : you either multiply or divide by 3 - but which one?

If the force is applied at the same distance from the fulcrum, then moving the nut further from the fulcrum will make it harder to crack - you will need more force. So you are correct : 360N.

Comment: So the book has it incorrectly as it gives 40 N as the answer?

Comment: Sorry, yes you are correct and the book is wrong, if the question is as you state. I shall correct my answer.